# How to set URL include to answer root level urls in django

Tags: django, url

I have these URL files:

project/url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include(public)),   <--- URL IN ERROR!!!!
    url(r'^member/', include(mviews)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

public/url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^login/', views.login)
]
```

mviews/url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

in the first URL file, the first URL where it says `include(public)` is erroring out.  How do I set it so public is the "home" url group?  Thanks.

Comment: `include('public.urls')`?

Comment: nope.  sorry...got error: `AttributeError: module 'public.urls' has no attribute 'urls'`

Comment: the name of file containing urls under `public` is `urls.py` right? Besides, I strongly recommend you go take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: correct.  it is called urls.py

Comment: Is your public module's "urls" file wrong?? In description it is public/url

Comment: ok, I have this line for the import:  `from public import urls as public`  still no go.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you have typo, your the name of file is wrong(url.py), It should be urls.py

And if above line holds then you can achieve grouping urls from public module by following

```
url(r'^home/', include('public.urls')),   
url(r'^member/', include(mviews)),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

Comment: Hi @Sachin, Thank you so much, but the problem here is that I now need `<domain>.com/home` in order to get to the homepage.  it is preferable to use `<domain>.com`.  How do I get around that?   Thanks.